# Fitting a complex GLM in R with probit link

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, probit

I am trying to fit a probit model for binomial data as follows.

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\%\textrm{alive} = \phi \ [ \textrm{a} - \textrm{b}t\ ]
\end{equation}

Where $\%alive$ is the dependent variable and $t$ is the independent variable. $\phi$ is the cumulative normal distribution function.  The coefficient $a$ is the intercept and $b$ is the slope.

The slope $b$ can be further modeled with the dependent variables $conc1$ and $conc2$. The coefficients here being $c$, $p1$ and $p2$.

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\frac{1}{\textrm{b}} = 10^{\textrm{c} - \textrm{p}_{1}conc1 -
\textrm{p}_{2}conc2}
\end{equation}

Equation $(1)$ can be fitted with a generalized linear model with probit link function, while Equation $(2)$ can be fitted with a logarithmic function.

How to fit a combined model as below ?

\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\%\textrm{alive} =  \phi \left [ \textrm{a}
- \frac{t}{10^{\textrm{c} - \textrm{p}_{1}conc1 -
\textrm{p}_{2}conc2}}  \right ]
\end{equation}

I am able to do it in two steps,

- First for each combination of $conc1$ and $conc2$, fit equation $(1)$ with `glm` and get values of $a$ and $b$.
- Then with values of $b$ fit equation $(2)$ with `lm` and get values of $c$, $p1$ and $p2$. But here negative values of b are sometimes computed.

How to perform this in a single step? Will it take care of the negative values for coefficient $b$ ?

Here is the two-step method in `R`.

### Data

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  conc1 = rep(c(3, 7, 5), 45),
  conc2 = c(rep(0, 45), rep(10, 45), rep(25, 45)),
  t = rep(1:15, each = 3),
  count.alive = c(48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 46, 48, 47, 45, 48, 
                  47, 45, 48, 48, 43, 47, 48, 41, 48, 48, 38, 48, 48, 35, 47, 48, 
                  32, 47, 48, 28, 49, 48, 24, 48, 49, 19, 48, 48, 16, 46, 48, 47, 
                  48, 47, 46, 48, 47, 42, 48, 48, 36, 48, 48, 27, 48, 48, 18, 47, 
                  48, 11, 48, 48, 5, 46, 48, 2, 46, 49, 0, 46, 47, 0, 42, 48, 0, 
                  42, 48, 0, 41, 48, 0, 40, 47, 0, 37, 48, 23, 48, 47, 0, 43, 48, 
                  0, 34, 49, 0, 22, 48, 0, 11, 48, 0, 3, 46, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 48, 
                  0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 44, 0, 
                  0),
  samp.size = c(50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 50, 51, 50, 50, 49, 50, 48, 49, 50, 
                48, 50, 49, 50, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 
                50, 49, 49, 50, 51, 49, 50, 51, 51, 48, 51, 50, 50, 48, 49, 49, 
                49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 48, 50, 50, 48, 49, 
                49, 48, 51, 50, 50, 50, 50, 48, 50, 51, 49, 51, 48, 50, 48, 49, 
                50, 50, 50, 51, 49, 50, 50, 50, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 48, 48, 
                49, 49, 50, 48, 51, 48, 48, 50, 51, 51, 50, 49, 49, 48, 50, 50, 
                49, 48, 49, 51, 50, 49, 49, 50, 49, 50, 48, 49, 49, 50, 49, 49, 
                50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 48)
)

df$percent.alive <- (df$count.alive / df$samp.size) * 100
head(df)
#>   conc1 conc2 t count.alive samp.size percent.alive
#> 1     3     0 1          48        50      96.00000
#> 2     7     0 1          48        50      96.00000
#> 3     5     0 1          48        50      96.00000
#> 4     3     0 2          48        49      97.95918
#> 5     7     0 2          48        49      97.95918
#> 6     5     0 2          48        49      97.95918
```

### Step 1

```
# Split df according to conc1 and conc2
df_list <- split(df, interaction(df$conc1, df$conc2))

# Fit equation (1) for each combination of conc1 and conc2
mod_glm2_step1_list <- 
  lapply(seq_along(df_list), 
         function(i) {
           glm(formula = "count.alive/samp.size ~ t",
               family = binomial(link = "probit"),
               data = df_list[[i]],
               weights = samp.size)
         })

# Get a data with coeficient b and the independent variables in equation (2)
df_b <- lapply(mod_glm2_step1_list,
                function(x) {
                  cbind(unique(x$data[, c("conc1", "conc2")]),
                        t(coef(x)))
                })

df_b <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_b)
colnames(df_b) <- c("conc1", "conc2", "a", "b")
```

### Step 2

```
# Fit equation (2) by logarithmic regression.
df_b$beta <- -1/df_b$b

# avoid logarithm of negative values
df_b$beta <- ifelse(df_b$beta <= 0, 0.0000001, df_b$beta)
df_b$log10_beta <- log(df_b$beta, 10)

mod_lm2 <- lm(formula = "log10_beta ~ conc1 + conc2",
              data = df_b)

# Get predicted values of b from mod_lm2
newdf <- cbind(df_b[, c("a", "conc1", "conc2")], 
                log10_beta = predict(mod_lm2, type = "response"))
newdf$b <- 10 ^ newdf$log10_beta

# Predicted values from mod_glm2
pred_glm2_list <- lapply(seq_along(mod_glm2_step1_list), 
                         function(i) {
                           mod <- mod_glm2_step1_list[[i]]
                           mod$coefficients[["t"]] <- newdf$b[i]
                           
                           data.frame(cbind(prop.alive = predict(mod,
                                                                 type = "response"), 
                                            mod$data))
                         })
pred_glm2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(pred_glm2_list)

# Plot the fits
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = count.alive/samp.size)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(data = pred_glm2, 
            aes(x = t, y = prop.alive, interaction(conc1, conc2)), 
            colour = "red")
```

[image]